# Why $localize `:@@ID:` does not working with standard angular unit test configuration

Tags: angular, internationalization, karma-jasmine

$localize ':@@ID:' is returning empty string always in a unit test’s.

The usage:

• In some component code I am using $localize':@@Some:' and everything works well when serving the app or building it for prod.
• I use the standard angular unit test setup/configuration

The problem:

When trying to test that the exact text is returned I get an empty string, and I want to avoid mocking the $localize to keep the test code simple.

Unit test code sample:

```
// in the unit test the $localize`:@@Some:` is returning always ‘’ 
const testResult = service.getInfo(param); // in the method we return $localize`:@@Some:`;
expect(testResult).toBe($localize`:@@Some:`);
```